# Console App Hangs after opens 108 DB Connections

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

I looked on several threads on stack and couldnt find an answer to this.

I have an app that opens an SQL connection makes a query compares a string and then outputs either a message relaying the item exists or creates the item in a second application.

The App gets stuck on the same value every time "J2y7W0Q1Tn"(This item exists in the DB), when I pause it Visual studio tells me connAm.Open(); will run next... I was using a using statement but needed my variables to be available outside of this scope.

I Tired to simplify this as much as possible and still include what might be necessary.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AcumaticaRoundRobin.RoundRobin;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

#region GetExistingTransactions
try {
string CleanTAccessCode = Regex.Replace(TAccessCode, "(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", "%", RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));

 SqlConnection connAM = new SqlConnection();

 connAM.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=myendpoint, 1433;Initial Catalog=DB;User Id=******;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connection Timeout=200000";
 connAM.Close(); // Closing Connections that may still be open from last loop
 connAM.Open(); //Open new connection
 SqlCommand AccessCodeResult = new SqlCommand("SELECT [UsrAccessCode] FROM [AmSecureClose].[dbo].[PMTran] WHERE CompanyID = 3 AND UsrAccessCode LIKE '" + CleanTAccessCode + "'", connAM)

  SqlDataReader AccessCodeResults = AccessCodeResult.ExecuteReader();
          if (AccessCodeResults.HasRows) {
            while (AccessCodeResults.Read()) {
             string FlatUseResult = AccessCodeResults.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : AccessCodeResults.GetString(0);

                                            #endregion

if (FlatUseResult.Equals(TAccessCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                                        {

                                                            Console.WriteLine(TAccessCode + " Exists Move to Next");
                                                            //connAM.Close();

                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {

                                                            //Jump into grid                                                       
                                                            context.CT303000Clear();
                                                            CT303000Content[] CT303000result2 = context.CT303000Submit(
                                                              new Command[] {
                                                      new Value { Value = ContractID, LinkedCommand = CT303000.Contract.ContractID },
                                                                    CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.ServiceCommands.NewRow,                                         
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Location ID*/TLocationIds, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.LocationId },
                                                                        //new Value { Value = /*DB Location*/TLocation, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.Location },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Deal Date*/TCreateDateS, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.Date },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Access Code*/TAccessCode, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.AccessCode },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Contract Code*/TContractCode, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.ContractCode },
                                                                        //new Value { Value = /*DB Contract Vin*/TContractVin, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.ContractVin },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Buyer ID*/TBuyerIdS, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.BuyerId },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB First Name*/TBuyerFName, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.BuyerFirstName },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Last Name*/TBuyerLName, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.BuyerLastName },
                                                                        //new Value { Value = /*DB Showing Sttus ID*/TStatusIdS, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.ShowingStatusId },
                                                                        new Value { Value = /*DB Presentation Status*/TPresentationStatus, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.PresentationStatus },
                                                                        //new Value { Value = /*DB Machine Name*/TKioskName, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.KioskName },
                                                                        new Value { Value = "1", LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.Quantity},
                                                                        new Value { Value = InventoryId, LinkedCommand = CT303000.UnbilledTransactions.InventoryID },                                                                            
                                                                        CT303000.Actions.Save
                                                              }


                                                             );

                                                            Console.WriteLine(TAccessCode + " Has Been Created Move to Next");
                                                            //connAM.Close();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }


                                        //}
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //No transactions for contract step to next Customer
                                    }

                                }
                                #endregion
                            }
                        }
                        //connPro.Close();
                    } // End Timeout Exception

                    catch (Exception TimeoutException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(TimeoutException.Message);
                        //if TimeoutException.Message 
                        //Console.ReadLine();
                        continue;
                    }
```

Comment: The connections last only a few seconds could that be causing leaked connections?

Comment: use [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Your code needs lot of refactoring. As far as I can understand you are calling this within a loop. Which means you are opening and closing connections multiple times. This sql query is a very simple one. You can think of collecting all parameter values within a loop and then call the sql for all parameters only once. Once you have the results you can loop through the results and display the values. After reading all the results you can close the connection. If you need more help, please post your full code.

Comment: Thank you @dotctor I was using using on reader but should have been using it with the connection to kill the connection.

Comment: @KosalaW you are right... As soon as I learn how to do that I will refactor it!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to structure the beginning of this call with an "using" statement that contained the connAM.Open(); before the second "SQLReader" using query and comparison loop started.

```
using (SqlConnection connAM = new SqlConnection()) { // Added this above the query enclosing the second using statement. 
 connAM.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=s*****, 1433;Initial Catalog=*****;User id=*****;Password=*****;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connection Timeout=200000";
                                            SqlCommand AccessCodeResult = new SqlCommand("SELECT [UsrAccessCode] FROM [AmSecureClose].[dbo].[PMTran] WHERE CompanyID = 3 AND UsrAccessCode LIKE '" + CleanTAccessCode + "'", connAM);
                                            connAM.Open();
                                            using (SqlDataReader AccessCodeResults = AccessCodeResult.ExecuteReader())
                                            {
```